# How to speed up DataAdapter.Fill in C# compact framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, compact-framework, sqldataadapter

I am performing a SQL query and writing found rows to temporary dataset. On windows mobile device this takes about 10-12 seconds. And after doing some debugging from device, I found that majority of that delay is cased by `adapter.Fill(tempDataset);` (7-9 seconds).

What can I do to fix this? What do I need to do to speed up DataAdapter.Fill? Why would this take so much time?

I am using `SQL Server CE` and `CompactFramework 3.5`.

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source='/pathto/MYDataBase.sdf'; Max Database Size = 512; Max Buffer Size = 4096;";
string strSql = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE LastName = '" + stringLastName +  "'";
SqlCeConnection mConnection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
SqlCeCommand mCommand = new SqlCeCommand(strSql, mConnection);
// Read all rows from the table into a dataset
SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(mCommand);
tempDataset = new MYDataSet();
adapter.Fill(tempDataset);
```

Comment: How large is the `dataset` you are returning?  That can be a factor in speed.

Comment: Not very large. Usually just one row. The actual database input is large, but sql query doesn't seem to take much time there.

Comment: Could it then be the medium that you are using?  Have you tried running the code on a desktop PC and compare the speed then?

Comment: Is there any alternative to DataAdapter? I need searched query in tempDataset to do more work later in the code.

Comment: There are alternatives, yes, but I can only make suggestions (and they may not be all that good) without seeing the code you are using for your mobile app.  [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978388.aspx) may be of some use to you though.

Comment: All other techniques would do more or less the same thing that is happening inside adapter.Fill(). You could try a SqlCeDataReader and open the connection yourself. Just to know if opening the connection is the problem or executing the command. First thing to check should be if LastName is indexed.

Comment: I tried to use SqlCeDataReader, and the main problem seems to be calling `DataSet.Load(reader, LoadOption)`. But how come even loading a single item (row) takes up so much time? What is base memory usage for DataSet Load?